# How to know image was binding in xaml in windows phone?

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, imageview, windows-phone-8.1

I have a image url and I binding it to xaml. But i don't know when it was show in xaml. So i can't put ProgressBar.
My code :

```
XAML:  <Image Grid.Row="1" x:Name="viewimg"/>
.CS : viewimg.Source = (ImageSource)new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFromString((string)          (App.Current as App).linkimage480);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ImageOpened` event, there is also `ImageFailed` in case there is a problem.

Edit:
Add `ImageOpened` event to your XAML:  `<Image Grid.Row="1" x:Name="viewimg"/>`

And then in code I would do:

```
BitmapImage bm = new BitmapImage();
bm.ImageFailed += delegate { // Code to execute when binding fails };
bm.UriSource = new Uri("http://imagesource.com", UriKind.Absolute);
viewimg.Source = bm;
```

Because I think when you add `ImageFailed` to XAML `Image` control and the failure occurs in your ImageSource then the event won't be fired.

Comment: Can you talk more about it? If can you code demo for me?Thank you very much.

Comment: I tried your way, but I found that when the image is displayed on XAML, the ImageOpened function appear.  I want a Progessbar to appear when the image has not  displayed on XAML and after the image was shown, I want Progessbar off.                                       private void viewimg_ImageOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
   progess.IsIndeterminate = true;
   BitmapImage bm = new BitmapImage();
   bm.ImageFailed += delegate {};
    bm.UriSource = new Uri((App.Current asApp).linkimage480, UriKind.Absolute);
   viewimg.Source = bm;
   progess.IsIndeterminate = false;}

Comment: In this case you, simply show your Progressbar when you start loading image (i.e. setting bm.UriSource) and then in your ImageOpened event hide it.

Comment: Ok, just so simple but I do not think. Than you very much.

Comment: Just for convenience, I'd change `bm.ImageFailed += delegate(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs args)` to `bm.ImageFailed += (sender, args) => {}`;